# Can this join be made into a generic CTE?

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

Quick preface: I'll say this is running against an oracle db in case that impacts answer, but CTEs are common to other RDBMS that I use (SQL Server, DB2) so I'm hoping for something I'll be able to use in those as well.

```
LEFT JOIN  
    (SELECT * 
     FROM 
         (SELECT 
              HH.*, 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HH.WORKSHEET_HISTORY_ID
                                 ORDER BY QQ.GOBLIN_HOBBIT_ID DESC) AS "INDICATOR"
          FROM 
              ILU.WORKSHEET_HOBBIT_RECOMMENDATIONS HH
          INNER JOIN 
              ILU.GOBLIN_HOBBIT QQ ON QQ.GOBLIN_HOBBIT_id = HH.GOBLIN_HOBBIT_id
          INNER JOIN 
              ILU.HOBBIT_master ZZ ON ZZ.HOBBIT_master_id = QQ.HOBBIT_master_id
          WHERE 
              ZZ.HOBBIT_CODE = '99'
              AND ZZ.ASSOCIATION_CODE <> 'GNDLF') Z
     WHERE 
         Z."INDICATOR" = 1) MITHRIL_HOBT ON MITHRIL_HOBT.WORKSHEET_HISTORY_ID = hst.WORKSHEET_HISTORY_ID
```

What I'd like to accomplish here is turning this join into a CTE. I can do that, but what I'm really interested in doing is being able to then call that CTE from my main query with different conditions:

```
WHERE 
    ZZ.HOBBIT_CODE = '%PARAMETER1'
    AND ZZ.ASSOCIATION_CODE <> '%PARAMETER2'
```

This may not be possible, and that's a valid answer. But to clarify I know that I could accomplish the same thing in other ways (creating a function) and those are fine, I'm just curious if it can be done as a CTE because CTE are easy to write quickly and clean up adhoc queries into more reusable slightly less adhoc queries.

(Finally, a quick description of what the join is structured in the weird way it is already: because I need to get the first row and it was the only way I could figure out to do that that didn't destroy performance. I even added an index where one was missing and the alternate method I used was still looping through the entire table.

FWIW the previous attempt that caused that issue was something like (this is within the SELECT rather than a subquery):

```sql
case when (   SELECT 1 FROM 
        ILU.WORKSHEET_HOBBIT_RECOMMENDATIONS HH
        INNER JOIN ILU.GOBLIN_HOBBIT QQ
            on QQ.GOBLIN_HOBBIT_id = HH.GOBLIN_HOBBIT_id
        INNER join ILU.HOBBIT_master ZZ
            on ZZ.HOBBIT_master_id = QQ.HOBBIT_master_id
         WHERE ZZ.HOBBIT_CODE='99'
         AND ZZ.ASSOCIATION_CODE <> 'GNDLF'
         and rownum = 1
) is not null then 1 else 0 end as MITHRIL_INDICATOR
```

(ps code is slightly obfuscated , I don't work for mordor)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does support CTEs, but the docs call it a `with` clause:

```
with CTE1 as
(
select HH.*, row_number() 
               over (
                 partition by HH.WORKSHEET_HISTORY_ID
                 order by QQ.GOBLIN_HOBBIT_ID desc
                    ) as "INDICATOR"
FROM ILU.WORKSHEET_HOBBIT_RECOMMENDATIONS HH
INNER JOIN ILU.GOBLIN_HOBBIT QQ
  on QQ.GOBLIN_HOBBIT_id = HH.GOBLIN_HOBBIT_id
INNER join ILU.HOBBIT_master ZZ
  on ZZ.HOBBIT_master_id = QQ.HOBBIT_master_id
WHERE ZZ.HOBBIT_CODE='99'
AND ZZ.ASSOCIATION_CODE <> 'GNDLF' 
)
, CTE2 as 
(
select * 
from CTE1
where INDICATOR = 1
)

select somestuff
from somewhere hst
LEFT join CTE2 
  on CTE2.Worksheet_history_id = hst.WORKSHEET_HISTORY_ID
```